# How do I neatly handle an Entity Framework search when there may be no results?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to run a very small Linq query with a where statement, and, if the element doesn't exist, I want to create a record that includes it.

Doing the following:

```
db.MyType.First(x=>x.name=="test")
```

or with `Where()` produces a yellow screen with `Sequence contains no elements` If it doesn't exist.

The way round it I found is to either wrap the whole thing in a try loop, or, use `FirstOrDefault()` then a `if (tmp == null) {my code...}`.

Both these method seems messy and I was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: IMO, FirstOrDefault() and then checking for null is the best option. All other possibilities require multiple calls to the databases and would define incoherent database states. Why do you think this approach is messy? All DB functions should have the possibility to return null, as there may be no matching result.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I haven't kept up with things (hobby programmer) and I recently went over some old code and was able to clean huge statements up, and, this is the last bit that looks "messy"... maybe I'm wrong then! Thanks

Comment: The FirstOrDefault() and then checking for null is fine. Consider the scenario where the element is automatically created if it doesn't exist. When the object is returned, you would not know if it already existed or if it was created during the call. That would definitely be messy. If you were always going to set all of the properties, regardless of whether the element already existed or not, then you could write a CreateOrReplace() method which handled this logic.